# Adaptive streaming in VideoJS using Wowza

Tags: javascript, html5-video, video.js, wowza, adaptive-bitrate

How we can achieve adaptive streaming in videojs player ? I know some paid version video players like JWplayer , flowplayer will support adaptive streaming but i need to achieve adaptive streaming in opensource html5 video player like videoJS . If we can do it adaptive streaming on server side/client side then also it is ok for me . I need some suggestions to do it .

Comment: See my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22484539/dynamic-smil-file-with-videojs-and-wowza-for-hls