# Dynamic smil file with videojs and wowza for HLS

Tags: amazon-ec2, video.js, wowza

I am using `wowza` with `amazon ec2` and I uploaded one `smil` file in amazon for testing. For `videojs` flash player, I am able to do multiple bitrate Http live streaming(`HLS`) using [`video-js-swf`](https://github.com/mangui/video-js-swf) plugin and a `smil` file. For all videos I need to create `smil` file and have to upload to amazon, and it takes lots of time.

Is there any way to use multiple rendition files only(without creating `smil` file and upload to `amazon ec2`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed wowza server configuration and created script which generates m3u8 and ts files using ffmpeg from mp4 files(which is having different bitrate videos).
We can directly add this m3u8 file in the video src(in web app). This will play http live streaming in ios and android devices.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if it answers your question, however Wowza has the following feature:
http://www.wowza.com/forums/showthread.php?14664-New-API-for-resolving-MediaList-%28SMIL-file-requests%29-through-Java-API

Comment: Thanks for the response . They have mentioned startup package , but i am not using any packages . I am using prebuilt amazon AMI .

Comment: i guess you'll need to not use Wowza AMI but install and configure Wowza manually, so any special license should be requested from Wowza and applied to your server.